# Draw a table with arrows in Latex

Tags: matrices

[image]

I want to draw this table in Latex please help me.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: You could use, e.g., a TikZ matrix. BTW: IMHO the tags are completely irrelevant for the problem. But because it seems, you think, that they are relevant, please give some details in the question, that make them relevant — or use other tags like [`tables`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables), [`diagrams`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) etc.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Please help us help you and provide some code that shows what you tried so far, preferably a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). There are many different ways to approach this and it would be great to know a bit more about the document set up and the context you are going to use this. On this site, there are already some solutions that might help you. This Q&A, for example, shows some possible approaches: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/637368/47927.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purists can even do it just using standard LaTeX `picture` environment, e.g.:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\unitlength}{10mm}
\parbox{4em}{Bishop's case}
\begin{picture}(3,3)(0,1.5)
  \multiput(0,0)(1,0){4}{\line(0,1){3}}
  \multiput(0,0)(0,1){4}{\line(1,0){3}}
  \put(.5,2.5){\makebox(0,0)[c]{A}}
  \put(1.5,2.5){\makebox(0,0)[c]{B}}
  \put(2.5,2.5){\makebox(0,0)[c]{C}}
  \put(.5,1.5){\makebox(0,0)[c]{D}}
  \put(1.5,1.5){\makebox(0,0)[c]{E}}
  \put(2.5,1.5){\makebox(0,0)[c]{F}}
  \put(.5,.5){\makebox(0,0)[c]{G}}
  \put(1.5,.5){\makebox(0,0)[c]{H}}
  \put(2.5,.5){\makebox(0,0)[c]{I}}
  \thicklines
  \put(1.4,1.4){\vector(-1,-1){.75}}
  \put(1.6,1.4){\vector(1,-1){.75}}
  \put(1.4,1.6){\vector(-1,1){.75}}
  \put(1.6,1.6){\vector(1,1){.75}}
  \put(0,-1){\makebox(3,0.9)[tl]{\parbox{3\unitlength}{\raggedright\tiny Cells sharing a common vertex are
        considered contiguous/adjacent}}}
\end{picture}
$\longrightarrow$
\begin{picture}(3,3)(0,1.5)
  \multiput(0,0)(1,0){4}{\line(0,1){3}}
  \multiput(0,0)(0,1){4}{\line(1,0){3}}
  \put(.5,2.5){\makebox(0,0)[c]{$j$}}
  \put(2.5,2.5){\makebox(0,0)[c]{$j$}}
  \put(1.5,1.5){\makebox(0,0)[c]{$j$}}
  \put(.5,.5){\makebox(0,0)[c]{$j$}}
  \put(2.5,.5){\makebox(0,0)[c]{$j$}}
\end{picture}
$\longrightarrow \mathsf{W}_{ij}=
\begin{array}{*{10}{c}}
   & \mathsf{A} & \mathsf{B} & \mathsf{C} & \mathsf{D} & \mathsf{E} & \mathsf{F}
  & \mathsf{G} & \mathsf{H} & \mathsf{I} \\
  \mathsf{A} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \mathsf{B} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \mathsf{C} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \mathsf{D} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \mathsf{E} & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
  \mathsf{F} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \mathsf{G} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \mathsf{H} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \mathsf{I} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

For the first tabular and its arrows (the most difficult part).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines,columns-width = 12 pt]
  A & B & C \\
  D & E & F \\
  G & H & I 
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [->]
    \draw (2-2) -- (1-1) ; 
    \draw (2-2) -- (1-3) ; 
    \draw (2-2) -- (3-1) ; 
    \draw (2-2) -- (3-3) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]